# Develop an iPhoto-like cocoa app for mac OSX

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, nscollectionview, nssplitview, iphoto

I plan to develop a mac OSX app that has a UI similar to that of iPhoto - a panel on the left and a grid view of images on the right. I am thinking of using NSSplitView to create two panels and using NSCollectionView for the grid.

I guess this must be a pretty popular and common UI pattern for mac apps. I am new to cocoa development. Can anyone with previous experience point me to any related cocoa code samples and design document?

Thanks a lot in advance.

N.B.

Answer (score 0):

This missing piece here is an NSOutlineView in source list mode, put that in your left pane. But otherwise seems like a good place to start.

You might also be interested to see what the developer of [Sonora](https://github.com/sonoramac/Sonora) approached this problem; although this is a music app the layout is almost the same.